# How can i resize UIView for an amount of UILabels and resize UILabels to fit text?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, uilabel

I have an UIView that it should contains UILabels, and these UILabels are not fixed if an UILabel is nil, i don't display it, and if is not i must resize the UILabel to fit text (they can be 2 ligne) and put it under another UILabel, and after i must resize the UIView container for the amount of this UILabels. this the Screen Shot that i want to do programmatically:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to used following two properties of label-

1. lineBreakMode
2. numberOfLine

when you use both of these properties then you will achieve what you want.

Comment: And how can i resize the UIView for the amount of this UILabels

Comment: from resize do you mean hight of view according to these labels.

Comment: And how can i know if the UILabel need 2 ligne?

Comment: that you can decide on the basis of number of characters and size of character of each font.

Answer (score 0):

UILabels can fit large amounts of text by automatically making the font smaller (see the minimum font size value in the Interface Builder).  Instead of labels, I would use UITextViews.  They fit large amounts of text by allowing the user to scroll.  To make them hidden, use change the hidden selector attribute of the UITextViews.  Because the UITextViews will never change in size, you can easily calculate how much to decrease the height of the UIView container by per UITextView.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to calculate the height of the labels (more specifically, the addition from the original height) one by one. Of course you should be able to do this systematically by having all the labels in an array.

You can use [NSString sizeWithFont:] methods (there are several with similar names) to calculate the height.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same font size then you can calculate the frame size for the label at run time depending upon the length of the text..
[See here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/07/10/resizing-uilabel-to-fit-text/)